# International(Uncut) version of Wolfenstein The New Order in Switzerland?

Tags: wolfenstein-the-new-order

As far as I know there is no law here that would forbid the use of the symbols which are forbidden in Germany and Austria. Steam says clearly that the available version is cut and just in German language. 
So why can't I activate the game in Switzerland* even if there shouldn't be a reason for that? Or am I missing something that allows me to buy the game?

*maybe in other European countries too, in France e.g.?

Comment: I'd suggest you buy import a boxed version from the UK, but I don't know if these require steam or are stand-alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After protests of players in Switzerland and Austria, who were unhappy with the unnecessary region lock, Bethesda has now deactivated the lock in both countries. You can now activate the international version of the game on Steam with all the swastikas.

This has been confirmed in an email from the [Bethesda Customer service on the Steam forum](http://steamcommunity.com/app/288570/discussions/0/522728086847132254/). English translation:

> I understand that there is no such law in Austria and that a censored game highly limits the fun. But the problem of geo-locks should have already been solved. So you can simply go to a retailer, who sells uncensored versions, buy it there, and enjoy the uncensored fun."

This also applies to Switzerland.

Source (German):
[4players.de News](http://www.4players.de/4players.php/spielinfonews/Allgemein/34726/2140871/Wolfenstein_The_New_Order|Regionensperre_nach_Protesten_entfernt_Unzensierte_Version_kann_in_Oesterreich_und_der_Schweiz_aktiviert_werden.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Bethesda Germany** is the distributor for Switzerland.  This means that, unfortunately, Switzerland is stuck with any censorship that is required by Germany.  Technically, this would apply the other way too - if Switzerland required the game to be censored, and Bethesda complied in order to allow distribution, the game would be censored in both Germany and Austria as well.

This is also the reason that the game you get in Switzerland (which is censored) is also dubbed in German (and from what I hear, has no way to change the language to another language).

---

**Edit:**  Apparently due to protests by players in Switzerland and Austria over the matter, Bethesda has decided to allow distribution/registration of the uncensored version of the game in these two countries.  See @DominicDeCoco's answer above for source links.  That said, I'm not sure if this means you can buy the uncensored game on Steam's digital store or if you have to buy the game from a different retailer - this will depend on if and when Steam updates their entries.

Answer (score 0):

It is worse than not being able to activate the game. Actually you cannot *launch* the game even if you activated it while using another country's IP.

So right now the only version to play a proper version of Wolfenstein is to use a VPN* to login to steam using an US IP.

Or, even better, ask for a full refund to show Bethesda that this kind of Geo-lock is unacceptable.

---

* Using a VPN from another country is against the Steam ToS. I've never heard about people being banned for it - after all, you are not using it to get cheaper prices from antoher country - but you have been warned.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but I don't think this provides a answer to my question. With a little research I found out, that it is nearly impossible to play the international version in Germany(as sad as it is, I know). But I don't see a reason why this Geolock affects Switzerland, couldn't read something about it.